# Delphi DragDrop Component in Threads

Tags: multithreading, delphi, drag-and-drop, delphi-2009

i use this component for processing drag and drop files
http://melander.dk/delphi/dragdrop

```
unit DragThread;

interface

uses
  Classes,DragDrop, DropTarget,DragDropFile,Dialogs,SysUtils;

type
  TDragThread = class(TThread)
  private
    { Private declarations }
    ArraysLength : Integer;
    DragComponent : TDropFileTarget;
    DragArray,HashsArray : Array of string;
    Procedure FDArray;
    //Procedure FDHArray;
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  Public
    Constructor Create(Com: TDropFileTarget);
    Destructor Destroy; Override;
  end;

implementation

{ TDragThread }

Constructor TDragThread.Create(Com: TDropFileTarget);
begin
   inherited Create(True);
   DragComponent := Com;
end;

Destructor TDragThread.Destroy;
begin
  //DragComponent.Free;
end;

Procedure TDragThread.FDArray;
var
  A : Integer;
begin
  SetLength(DragArray,DragComponent.Files.Count);
  SetLength(HashsArray,DragComponent.Files.Count);

  ShowMessage(IntToStr(DragComponent.Files.Count)); // just working in the first time !!

for A := 0 to DragComponent.Files.Count -1 do begin
      DragArray[A] := DragComponent.Files[A];
      //ShowMessage(DragComponent.Files[A]);

   end;
  ArraysLength := DragComponent.Files.Count-1;
  //ShowMessage(DragComponent.Files[0]);
end;

procedure TDragThread.Execute;
begin
  { Place thread code here }
  FDArray;
end;

end.
```

the strange thing that the Drop process working just one time then the DragComponent.Files.Count gives 0 for ever .!!

that's how i call it

```
procedure TForm1.DropFileDrop(Sender: TObject; ShiftState: TShiftState;
  APoint: TPoint; var Effect: Integer);
var
  DropThread : TDragThread;
begin
 DropThread := TDragThread.Create(DropFile);
 DropThread.Resume;
end;
```

i want to know why this happened and thanks in advance :) .

Comment: Does it help it you read the file names from `DragComponent` in the main thread and leave the processing to the worker thread? I have no experience of this drag and drop component so I don't know what its threading rules are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't operate VCL components from other threads.

There's no guarantee that the component's drop-event information will continue to be valid once the drop event has completed.

Copy all the information you need out of the component when you construct the thread (i.e., fully populate `DragArray`) and then use that cached data when executing the thread. Don't store a reference in `DragComponent` or you might be tempted to use it from the thread's `Execute` method, which you really shouldn't do.

Comment: Thank you so much Rob you're right there's no guarantee that the information stills valid i don't know how i didn't got this !! :D